# Tutorials for Mozilla Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Can any one suggest a good tutorial for Mozilla rhino. What i want to do is to validate a form in java swing with javascript.
The official tutorial page on the mozilla website is not clear about actual coding, it only shows its features in code fragments.

There was also a page about scripting java inside javascript. Would it be better to use it instead of JSP for small applications, personally i didn't like java in web development compared to PHP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best thing to do is [play with the examples supplied](https://web.archive.org/web/20140304184825/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Examples).

Also, I have found these to be helpful:

- If you are on windows [this is how to setup your environment](https://web.archive.org/web/20130429162119/http://www.rhino-tutorial.buss.hk/tutorials/compile-javascript-file) and a simple intro (having you compile and run your first file).
- This talks about how [Rhino ECMAScript Engine is part of Java6](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things9/index.html) and how to leverage Java and scripting with the Java Scripting API.
- [This video from Google IO 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BttI-y9VzXQ) was very helpful
- Rhino absolutely depends on one's inclination and interest in Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. These are good enough for me to get started. I really hope this experiment will help me in my career.

Comment: Can you please update the setup your enviroment link?!

Comment: @Cucu ..updated with archive.org version. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

not easy to find a good tutorial.
You can check the Chapter 12 of the book "Javascript: The Definitive Guide 6th Edition", to get some very good insights.
But, if you don't like java I think it's going to be a nightmare.

Comment: I do like JAVA a lot. Only with web applications, i felt that php is more flexible, and less coding also.

Comment: Well, at this time, it might not be easy to get one, but it is not impossible to accumulate one. May be one day, my notes on this will help someone like me.